# how can I rotate an opengl 3d object to point to a GPS position (lat, long)?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, gps, orientation

I have a 3D arrow drawn with OpenGL that points to the coordinates (0, 0, 0) and I want it to point to a specific GPS location depending on my GPS position and Orientation.

I've tried calculating the azimuth (with my phone's orientation) and adjusting it to be the real north (not the magnetic north).

```
SensorManager.getOrientation(remappedRotationMatrix, orientation);

    // convert radians to degrees
    float azimuth = orientation[0];
    azimuth = azimuth * 360 / (2 * (float) Math.PI);
    GeomagneticField geoField = new GeomagneticField(
                 Double.valueOf(loc.getLatitude()).floatValue(),
                 Double.valueOf(loc.getLongitude()).floatValue(),
                 Double.valueOf(loc.getAltitude()).floatValue(),
                 System.currentTimeMillis());
    // converts magnetic north into true north
    azimuth -= geoField.getDeclination();
```

Then getting the bearing from my Location to the Location I want to point.

```
    target.setLatitude(42.806484);
    target.setLongitude(-1.632482);

    float bearing = loc.bearingTo(target); // (it's already in degrees)
    if (bearing < 0) {
        bearing = bearing + 360;
    }

    float degrees = bearing - azimuth;
    if (degrees < 0) {
        degrees = degrees + 360;
    }
```

and calculating the degrees I have to rotate the arrow

```
gl.glRotatef(degrees, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
arrow.draw(gl);
```

Is there someway to do it? Could another possibility be to convert the GPS position to the OpenGL coordinates and use GLU.gluLookAt to point to it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This seem to be purely a math problem.

Your question is pretty vague, I don't think I can help you without understanding more precisely how your scene is set up and what you want.

Do you know how to use 3D rotation matrices? If not, you probably should learn how they work.

Comment: I've editted the question to show some of my code so people can understand what I'm asking better, I just couldn't do it yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be complicated to calculate the bearing and then rotate the arrow by the degrees you get.  I have done the same in 2D although not in OpenGL. I based my code on the Radar sample (http://apps-for-android.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Radar/).  Here is how I draw the 2D arrow:

```
    double bearingToTarget = mBearing - mOrientation;

    // Draw an arrow in direction of target
    canvas.rotate((float) bearingToTarget, center, center);
    final int tipX = center;
    final int tipY = center-radius;
    canvas.drawLine(center, center, tipX, tipY, mArrowPaint);
    final int tipLen = 30;
    final int tipWidth = 20;
    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(tipX, tipY);
    path.lineTo(tipX + tipWidth/2, tipY + tipLen);
    path.lineTo(tipX - tipWidth/2, tipY + tipLen);
    path.lineTo(tipX, tipY);
    path.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, mArrowPaint);
    canvas.restore();
```

mBearing is calculated using the method GeoUtils.bearing from the Radar sample which takes care of the complicated math. mOrientation is just the orientation from the sensor listener.  So the idea is to compute the difference between the bearing of the GPS location you want to point to (mBearing) and the current orientation of the phone (mOrientation).  This gives us the angle bearingToTarget.  We then rotate the view about its center by that angle before drawing the arrow along the y axis.  This is the same as drawing the arrow rotated by bearingToTarget degrees.

You should be able to apply the same logic in OpenGL by rotating the view about the center of the screen by bearingToTarget degrees before you draw the arrow.  Exactly what point you rotate about depends on how your view is set up.  To make it simple, make the starting point of your arrow at the origin.  Then you can simply rotate about the origin using glRotatef.  Otherwise you would first need to translate to the center of the rotation, rotate and then translate back again (this is the common OpenGL technique for rotation about a point).

Comment: I've editted the question to show some of my code so people can understand what I'm asking better, I just couldn't do it yesterday.

Comment: Your code looks correct.  What exactly isn't working when you run it?

Comment: The arrow goes round and round except if I keep the phone in a specific position in which it seems to work, but if I move the phone a little bit the arrow gets crazy. I think that the phone's sensor is the problem, the getOrientation function gives very different data and I can't find the way to not moving the arrow if it's not necessary